# Blur, Threshold, Smooth Edges captured

Tags: c++, opencv

Hey peeps what am trying to do here is to load a video play it, capture frames while the video is played and output it in new Window. This is what the below code does atm.

But i want to take it to the next level now by adding blur to the captured frame and threshold it perhaps smooth edges before or after threshold.

```
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>
#include<opencv\ml.h>
#include<opencv\cxcore.h>
#include<fstream>



int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
//Main Window
    cvNamedWindow( "DisplayVideo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( argv[1] ); //Video captured and stored in CAPTURE
    IplImage* frame; //Image captured and stored in FRAME

int num=0;
char s [20];

while(1) {
    num++;
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if( !frame ) break;
        cvShowImage( "DisplayVideo", frame );
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if( c == 27 ) break;
        if (c == 'f')
            {
            sprintf(s,"frame%d.jpg",num);
            cvSaveImage(s,frame);
            cvNamedWindow("FrameWindow", 0);
            cvShowImage("FrameWindow",frame);
            }
        }



cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow("DisplayVideo" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The function cvQueryFrame grabs a frame from camera or video file,
>   decompresses and returns it. This function is just a combination of
>   cvGrabFrame and cvRetrieveFrame in one call. The returned image should
>   not be released or modified by user.

So first you want to copy the frame to a place in memory where you have control.

```
IplImage* img;
cvCopyImage(frame,img);

cvSmooth(img,img,...);
cvThreshold(img,img,...);

...
cvReleseImage(&img);
```

cvSmooth IS blur. I'm not sure what difference you see between smoothing and blurring. Check out the OpenCV C reference for other image operations you can do.